# FragmentTransaction commit blocking Async Tasks from running - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I am creating an app in Xamarin. I am trying to add a SupportMapFragment to the current Fragment I am on using the ChildFragment with this method:

```
        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        transaction.Add(Resource.Id.graph_fragment_holder, fragment).Commit();

         showMap.Click += async (sender, e) =>
         {
             await GetUserAddress();
             string url = "http://housechecker.co.uk/api/display.php";
             JsonValue json = await FetchUserAsync(url);

             string jsonString = json.ToString();
             addressList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Address>>(jsonString);
             await getCoordinates();
             SetUpMap();
         };

        showMap.CallOnClick();
```

If I remove those 3 lines, that Click event will run fine and I can receive all the data. I am not sure if the commit that is being called by the transaction is blocking the thread from performing the async methods I am trying to call.

Anyone got any idea about a solution? Thanks!

Note: This code is all inside a Fragment.

Comment: maybe add more relevant code? How do the asnyc methods look like, where do you call them? Where do you execute the fragment transaction? ..

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe added some more to my question. however I don't get what you mean by "where do i execute it", is that not done by the commit function?

Comment: the structure of your code is completely unclear... imagine, you don't know anything about the problem and provide us all necessary information. the context is missing. These code snippets have to be in methods. These methods are in classes (post just the relevant parts and explain how the components interact with each other).

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe sorry for the vagueness, I have updated the question, if you need anything else just lemme know